# cant display image from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am having trouble displaying images from my db, when i show it without the header i get the image data but when i give it the `header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` nothing is displayed.

in my db i have the image column as a longblob.

```
$host='******';
$user='******';
$pass='******';
$db='******';
$tbl_name='******';

//connect to db
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

$id=addslashes($_REQUEST['id']);

$image=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'");
$image=mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$image=$image['image'];

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

echo "<img src='$image' />";
```

?>`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `img` tag. You want to output the raw data only:

```
echo $image;
```

Note that `addslashes()` is not adequate protection against SQL injection. You would have to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` (or `intval()`).

Comment: i tried it with the `mysql_real_escape_string()` and removed the `img` tag, but still it wont show the image...

Comment: @Slarti then remove the header() again and see whether there are any PHP error messages.

Comment: unfortunatly no, im on my schools server and i cant access my own server from here